# Can you modify the DotNetNuke Breadcrumb skin object programmatically?

Tags: dotnetnuke-module

When developing custom modules that have a additional pages aside from the standard View.ascx and Edit.ascx controls, I would like to be able to add items to the breadcrumb skin object programmatically from my module.  Is this possible in DNN 6.2+?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  You have to write your own breadcrumb skin object. Then you would provide a hook of some sort that would allow you to add to the path. We had to do something similar in the menu so wrote our own menu provider. The breadcrumb skin object is a little different but same idea.